# Does Lit have mounted lifecycle like Vue?

Tags: blockly, lit

My Vue app did set up a Blockly element in `mounted`. I'm updating the app by using Lit. In `connectedCallback` the target element which hosts Blockly is not contained in the document.

```js
connectedCallback(): void {
    super.connectedCallback()
    const editorDiv = this.renderRoot.querySelector('#visual-editor-div')
    Blockly.inject(editorDiv)
}

render() {
    return html`
      <div id="visual-editor-div"></div>
    `
 }
```

Error message was:

```
Error: container is not in current document.
```

Is there the way to inject Blockly after container mounted in Lit?

Comment: I also tried `firstUpdated` then got the same error.

Comment: Or can I inject Blockly to shadow dom?

Comment: Create a ref and do the inject in firstUpdated.